# Spring TestRestTemplate not encoding "+" character

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am doing a SAML request that has a base64 encoded parameter called "SAMLRequest".  The problem is that the "+" characters are not getting  URL encoded (it is working fine for other character such as "="). When the request is received on the server it is considered an invalid document because all the "+" characters are now space " " characters.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    String base64SamlRequest = Base64.encode(... some payload ...);
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(base64SamlRequest, headers);
    restTemplate.exchange(endpoint+"&SAMLRequest="+base64SamlRequest, method, httpEntity, String.class);
```

I have also tried templating with `SAMLRequest={base64SamlRequest}` as part of the URL.

```
restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, method, httpEntity, String.class, base64SamlRequest);
```

With logging enabled `logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG` I can see that `+` character are plain text in the url parameter (not encoded).

How do I force these to be encoded?  Or is there something I can change in the above code to encode it properly?

Comment: check this link ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628738/strange-base64-encode-decode-problem

Comment: @AmolRaje I tried with `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);` but still no good.

Comment: ok.. after encoding into string change plus character to %2B and then pass to the url

Comment: `base64SamlRequest = base64SamlRequest .replaceAll("+", "%2B")` and then pass to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked this out now.  Turns out that I need to emulate a Form Submission for a SAML request. The rules for URL encoding form data are different.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    String base64SamlRequest = Base64Utils.encodeToString(authnRequest.getBytes());

    MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    form.add("username", "user");
    form.add("password", "password");
    form.add("SAMLRequest", base64SamlRequest);

    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(form, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endpoint, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Spring practice for doing Base64 encoded String operations that are going into a URL is to use Spring's [Base64Utils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Base64Utils.html#encodeToUrlSafeString-byte:A-):

```
String base64SamlRequest = Base64Utils.encodeToUrlSafeString(... some byte-wise payload ...);
```

This ensures all characters get escaped properly during the encode process.

See [this example](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/notify/LetsChatNotifier.java) in the Spring-Boot Admin console code.

For more info see the [Base64Utils source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/Base64Utils.java), which under the covers uses the [Base64#getUrlEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder--) to encode the string.

Comment: This works from a client perspective but the server can no longer parse the String (probably because OpenSAML it is not using the decodeToUrlSafeString).  Decoding using `Base64Utils.decodeFromUrlSafeString` works but `Base64Utils.decodeFromString` fails.  I can't change the Base64 library the server is using because it is their code.